# HTTP client to Fetch and Store images from Server using C

Tags: c, sockets, file-io, httpclient

I was having problem in storing .png images , fetched from HTTP server using a C code . I must mention that the images are successfully fetched from server as i analysed wireshark while running the code and content length in header matches buffer size. When i write the buffer data to a .png file using fwrite like this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic of writing upto `*pt != '\0'` is not correct in this loop

```
while((c=*pt)!='\0')
        {
            fwrite(&c, sizeof(c),1, fp);
            pt++;;
        }
```

There can be `'\0'` character anywhere in the binary data of .png file. So you will not write data after that, hence you are seeing your file size smaller than file size on server.

You should parse the HTTP headers and get value for `Content-Length`, which gives size of data in bytes and read those many from server and write in local file.

Look for HTTP RFC for more details about the protocol.

There are other problems in your code like

```
char *pt=malloc(100000);
pt=strstr(rep,"\r\n\r\n");
```

With this `malloc()` to `pt` is not required and leaks the memory.

Comment: Now i tried what you proposed but still file is not correctly being written . please see the modified  code in my question:

Comment: @Shubham, problem is with `strcat(rep,server_r);` and that loop. The logic should be first get `Content-Length` from header and then read those many bytes after `"\r\n\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file for output in binary mode , give `FILE *fp` the flag `wb`.

Also, why do you try to write byte by byte ? try `fwrite(pt,10000,1,fp)`